# How to revert git pull request in Visual Studio online?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

A team member made a pull request using git for visual studio online. It was approved and merged in successfully, however we would like to undo that and revert to the state of the branch prior to the PR.

Locally, I'm aware of a way to do this. It would be to get a version of our master branch, revert to the earlier version in a branch, and commit it like a standard PR. However, is there not a way in the VSTFS online to simply "undo"?

Thanks

**Update**

My apologies. I didn't clarify that this was for TFS 2015, and apparently that is not available as a feature in 2015.

Comment: You might need to clarify your question. I (and Andy answering below) mistakenly understood it as VSTS, since you write Visual Studio Online, but it seems from your comment to Andys answer that you actually mean TFS 2015 (on-prem).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can revert the completed pull request directly in VSTS:

1. Navigate to the completed Pull Request : Code >> Pull Request >>
   Completed
2. Select and open the Pull Request which you want to be reverted.
3. Click **More Actions** (Behind the `Delete source Branch` button) >>
   **Revert**
4. Click **Revert** on the opened **Revert pull request** dialog.
5. Click **Create Pull Request** in the revert succeeded dialog.

   `Revert succeeded in creating the new branch Dev-revert-from-master.`
6. Click **Create**  >> **Approve** >> **Complete** >> Enable the
   checkbox for `Delete Dev-revert-from-master after merging` >>
   **Complete merge**

Check the code in Master branch, it should be reverted back.

[image]

Comment: You must have a different version of the UI, because I cannot see that "more details" option. Is there a way to do it for VSTFS 2015? Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/pGy9o

Comment: @Kat You asked for Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), So I provided the solution for VSTS.  The feature is not supported in TFS 2015. You can upgrade to TFS 2017 or later version to use the **Revert** feature.

Comment: [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests#revert-a-pull-request) on this process

Comment: Even though I'm using Azure, this gave me enough information to infer how to perform the same process on their site. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> is there not a way in the VSTFS online to simply "undo"?

Not that I know of: reverting, and then pushing the new commit as a new PR remains the simplest option.