# Does reverting a pull request leave history in Azure?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to revert a pull request in Azure Devops using:

[How to revert git pull request in Visual Studio online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352126/how-to-revert-git-pull-request-in-visual-studio-online/46357479)

Question is: does reverting leave a history? I'm trying to revert a mistake on my company remote repo. So preference is not to leave a log showing I reverted/etcc., but if it's safer, I don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reverting a PR will leave the history intact.

Reverting a PR uses the `git revert` command which creates a *new* commit on the branch. The new commit is the exact opposite of the commit to be reverted, effectively undoing those changes. In the case of "Reverting a PR", oftentimes the commit is a Merge Commit, meaning the `revert` command will use the argument `-m1` which undoes the entire merge and reverts back to the first parent. This would be equivalent to individually reverting every commit that was brought in by the merge. Once you have created your new branch containing the reverted commit, then you can PR that branch into the target branch just like you normally would.

If you don't want the history to show the original PR and the subsequent revert, you would have to `reset` your target branch (e.g. `main`, `master`, `develop`, etc.) to just before the PR you want to get rid of. For shared branches this is generally frowned upon, and I would only do it if the following conditions are met:

1. The PR you want to "delete" is the most recent PR. (No new commits you would want to keep exist on the branch after the PR you want to undo.)
2. You can be reasonably sure that no one who uses the repo already has the commits you want to "delete" in any of their branches yet. Or, you're willing to everyone know that if they are using those commits, they'll need to rebuild their branches (either with a fancy `rebase --onto` or by making a new branch/resetting and then cherry picking their own commits onto the new branch).

If those conditions are met and you prefer to delete the commits, then you do this with:

```
git fetch
# inspect the branch and make sure you don't now see new commits after the PR to delete
# decide which commit-id you want to reset back to
git reset --hard commit-id
git push --force-with-lease
```

Again, force pushing a shared branch is generally not recommended, but in private repos with small teams it's doable. That being said, when you do it, having good documentation for how to "rebuild" a branch will likely be appreciated by those who need it.

**Side Note:** After reverting, if you ever change your mind and decide you want it back, it gets a little hairy as you must decide whether to "[Revert the Revert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67433104/184546)".